# Add status by conditions (by datetime) dataframe pandas using transform or something else

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, transform, columnsorting

I have following dataframe

```
    id   value                 date
0    1   first  2022.06.25 16:47:11
1    1  second  2022.06.25 17:47:11
2    1  second  2022.06.26 12:47:11
3    2   first  2022.06.18 16:47:11
4    2  second  2022.06.18 16:55:11
5    3   first  2022.06.15 15:00:11
6    3   third  2022.06.15 16:47:11
7    3  fourth  2022.06.15 18:47:11
8    3   fifth  2022.06.17 10:47:11
9    4  second  2022.06.01 16:47:11
10   4   fifth  2022.06.02 07:47:11
11   5   first  2022.06.25 16:47:11
12   6   first  2022.06.10 16:47:11
13   6  second  2022.06.10 19:47:11
14   6   third  2022.06.11 08:47:11
15   7  fourth  2022.06.26 10:47:11
16   7   fifth  2022.06.27 15:47:11
```

I need to add new column 'status' with values according to conditions after sorting df by id and date and groupby id
1). for the first two rows in groups, if id has the same date (day) 'status'== 'ok'
2). if in group we have id with several date, and difference between date of first row and other date in group more than 24 hours, 'status'=='nok'
3). if in group we have more than 2 id with the same date, for id after second, status =='norm'
4). if in group id with different date (day), and difference less then 24 hours, 'status'=='norm'
'''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,7],
                'value'  : ["first","second","second","first",
                            "second","first","third","fourth",
                            "fifth","second","fifth","first",
                            "first","second","third","fourth","fifth"],
                   'date' : ['2022.06.25 16:47:11','2022.06.25 17:47:11','2022.06.26 12:47:11','2022.06.18 16:47:11','2022.06.18 16:55:11', '2022.06.15 15:00:11','2022.06.15 16:47:11','2022.06.15 18:47:11','2022.06.17 10:47:11',
'2022.06.01 16:47:11','2022.06.02 07:47:11', '2022.06.25 16:47:11', '2022.06.10 16:47:11','2022.06.10 19:47:11','2022.06.11 08:47:11',
'2022.06.26 10:47:11', '2022.06.27 15:47:11']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
df=df.sort_values(['id','date'])
df['time'] = df.groupby(['id'])['date'].transform(lambda x: x-df.groupby('id')['date'].head(1))

print (df)
```

I try add column time, where i subtract first date of group from date in group to understand how much hours last from the date of first row. I try transform function, but function apply only for first row in groups.
next step would be on base of the time difference add 'status', but i stuck o nthe transform, and don't understand what am i doing wrong?

'''

```
    id   value                date   time
0    1   first 2022-06-25 16:47:11 0 days
1    1  second 2022-06-25 17:47:11    NaT
2    1  second 2022-06-26 12:47:11    NaT
3    2   first 2022-06-18 16:47:11 0 days
4    2  second 2022-06-18 16:55:11    NaT
5    3   first 2022-06-15 15:00:11 0 days
6    3   third 2022-06-15 16:47:11    NaT
7    3  fourth 2022-06-15 18:47:11    NaT
8    3   fifth 2022-06-17 10:47:11    NaT
9    4  second 2022-06-01 16:47:11 0 days
10   4   fifth 2022-06-02 07:47:11    NaT
11   5   first 2022-06-25 16:47:11 0 days
12   6   first 2022-06-10 16:47:11 0 days
13   6  second 2022-06-10 19:47:11    NaT
14   6   third 2022-06-11 08:47:11    NaT
15   7  fourth 2022-06-26 10:47:11 0 days
16   7   fifth 2022-06-27 15:47:11    NaT
```

expected result

```
id   value                  date    status
0    1   first 2022-06-25 16:47:11  ok
1    1  second 2022-06-25 17:47:11  ok
2    1  second 2022-06-26 12:47:11  norm
3    2   first 2022-06-18 16:47:11  ok
4    2  second 2022-06-18 16:55:11  ok
5    3   first 2022-06-15 15:00:11  ok
6    3   third 2022-06-15 16:47:11  ok
7    3  fourth 2022-06-15 18:47:11  norm
8    3   fifth 2022-06-17 10:47:11  nok
9    4  second 2022-06-01 16:47:11  ok
10   4   fifth 2022-06-02 07:47:11  norm
11   5   first 2022-06-25 16:47:11  ok
12   6   first 2022-06-10 16:47:11  ok
13   6  second 2022-06-10 19:47:11  ok
14   6   third 2022-06-11 08:47:11  norm
15   7  fourth 2022-06-26 10:47:11  ok
16   7   fifth 2022-06-27 15:47:11  nok
```

maybe exist more easier ways to add necessary status on the aforementioned conditions and i just complicate solution?
I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Doing two conditions with `np.select` , by `cumcount` we get the first 2 , by the `transform` `first` we get the diff not more than 1 day

```
ct = df.groupby('id').cumcount()
s = (df.date - df.groupby('id')['date'].transform('first'))<=pd.Timedelta('1 day')
df['status'] = np.select([s & (ct<=1),s & (ct>1),~s],['ok','norm','nok'])
df
Out[59]: 
    id   value                date status
0    1   first 2022-06-25 16:47:11     ok
1    1  second 2022-06-25 17:47:11     ok
2    1  second 2022-06-26 12:47:11   norm
3    2   first 2022-06-18 16:47:11     ok
4    2  second 2022-06-18 16:55:11     ok
5    3   first 2022-06-15 15:00:11     ok
6    3   third 2022-06-15 16:47:11     ok
7    3  fourth 2022-06-15 18:47:11   norm
8    3   fifth 2022-06-17 10:47:11    nok
9    4  second 2022-06-01 16:47:11     ok
10   4   fifth 2022-06-02 07:47:11     ok
11   5   first 2022-06-25 16:47:11     ok
12   6   first 2022-06-10 16:47:11     ok
13   6  second 2022-06-10 19:47:11     ok
14   6   third 2022-06-11 08:47:11   norm
15   7  fourth 2022-06-26 10:47:11     ok
16   7   fifth 2022-06-27 15:47:11    nok
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!!! I admire how short desicions could be. My was (just in view) much difficult.